# Exclude person if he gave to certain account (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to add a condition to my search that when a person has given to a certain bank account, then exclude him entirely in my search results. The search is grouped by personId.

In this following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/046ef9/6), I was only able to exclude the **transactions** to bank accounts 1 and 5, hiding personId '4' and '5', but personId '1' would still show up on my search result.

I thought of also adding a new column labeled 'Do not include person' on my search, and mark a person as 'Do not include' if he has given to bank accounts 1 or 5. However, I am unable to find an aggregate function to do so with the CASE function.

Let me know your thoughts!

-Edit: updated SQL Fiddle link to show final query.

Comment: What do you expect the final output to look like?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @VishnuKunchur I'd want to remove the row with personId '1' from the final output.

Comment: @Error_2646 Oracle database

Comment: @Francis My answer should work fine for Oracle, as long as I'm understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use exists

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table_Name T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM Table_Name T2
            WHERE T1.PersonID = T2.PersonID
              AND T2.To_BankAcc IN ('1','5')
         )
```

Comment: It worked. Added 'Group by personid' to the final line and modified first line to be 'SELECT personid, sum(amount)'. Not sure what 'Select 1 From' does but I'll do some more digging myself. Thanks!